# GRUB shows up after installing upstart-sysv in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, upstart, systemd

I was trying to configure FTP in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS last night, and accessing it failed. I tried some "solution" by some guy in a forum (forgot where exactly) and installed `upstart-sysv`in my system. Now, the problem is, my laptop now starts to show the GRUB when I am turning it on. Btw, I installed my Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

How can I bring it back to the way it was? Where it doesn't show the GRUB manager, and boot straight ahead instead? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I did a `sudo apt-get purge upstart-sysv` command, and `sudo update-initramfs -u` after. It solved my problem. Hmmmm... Weird.